# Refresh/Reload Modal ViewController on Button Click

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

How is it possible to refresh/reload a modal view controller on button click?
I need to reload an entire view controller .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dismiss your modal view controller and present it again setting the animation parameter to NO.
Another solution would be to embed your ViewController in a UINavigationController as its RootViewController (and present this one modally). When you have to reload your ViewController, simply use:

```
 - (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

on the navigationController with an array containing a new instance of your ViewController.

Anyway, are you really sure you can't simply reset all the contents of your UIViewController without "reloading" it from scratch?